# How to go to the next date in a time series without using timedelta

Tags: python, date, time-series, anaconda

I have a very basic question, would appreciate anyone guiding.

If I have a long time series starting as below, which skips certain dates (eg holidays etc). I want to read values against each date and perform further calculations using them. The index column is in datetime format, but if I use timedelta(1) to go to the next date, the code gets confused when I reach a missing date, (eg 2017-12-18):

```
2017-12-15   -1.354562
2017-12-16   -0.911684
2017-12-17   -0.635944
2017-12-20   -0.250884
2017-12-21    0.108373
2017-12-22    0.293125
2017-12-26    0.396881
2017-12-27    0.683924
2017-12-28    0.805295
2017-12-29    0.235709
```

My question is what is the simplest way to read value in the next date provided. I can increase the date every time by one and check if it exists in this time series, else again increase it and so on. But I want to avoid doing this check again and again in the code, if possible.

Could someone clarify what is the right command here to automatically go to the next date and read the value against it.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the programming language as a `tag`. What calculations do you want to perform?

Comment: Thanks - have added both Python and Anaconda as tags. I want to sequentially read the score for each date and compare it with a fixed number (eg 1), and perform some action (eg buying of a stock) if the score is >1 or < -1. And I am unable to use ** date = date +1 ** because the code gets confused when it reaches a date that's not there in the time series

Comment: You should give us some code you have written so people can have an idea what issues you are having without guessing. Base one the data you are showing me and a lot of assumption I think you can do. for thedate, thevalue in stream_of_ data: ...

Answer (score 0):

If "a long time series" has already sorted by date

```py
with open('a_long_time_series.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        value = line.split()[1]
        # process value
```

If not sorted

```py
with open('a_long_time_series.txt') as f:
    for line in sorted(f.readlines()):
        value = line.split()[1]
        # process value
```